# Javascript date.setSeconds working as expected in Debugger but not in script

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a function that sets a cookie as follows:

```
function createCookieWithDuration(name, value, duration) {
    const date = new Date();
    console.log(`date now: ${date}`);
    date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + duration);
    console.log(`adjusted date by ${duration} seconds: ${date}`);
    document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; expires=${date}; path=/`;
}
```

Now, if I do this line for line in the debugger it works as expected:
[image]

But when I let the script run and log to the console I get 3 minutes added on as well as the seconds:

[image]

Is there a weird javascript timing thing that I'm missing here?

Comment: It works just right on chrome 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10. I don't see any extra seconds added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code, but make sure that duration is in miliseconds, so if you want to add 2 seconds you need to pass 2000, or if you're passing seconds just add duration * 1000 in code.

```js
function createCookieWithDuration(name, value, duration) {
    const date = new Date();
    console.log(`date now: ${date}`);
    const newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + duration);
    console.log(`adjusted date by ${duration}: ${newDate}`);
    document.cookie = `${name}=${value}; expires=${newDate}; path=/`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `setSeconds()` refers to current time. You may use `alert()` to see even bigger differences.
However, the following will work as you expect:
Replace:

```
date.setSeconds(date.getSeconds() + duration);
```

With:

```
    date.setHours(date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds()+ duration, 0);
```

Note that I zero milliseconds, you may handle it as you like.
see working example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/site2goal/8dr0smot/20/)